# Bootstrap getting start

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

All, I am a nerd in Bootstrap. After I was reading the [Bootstrap document](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html), I start to do some experiment in jsfiddle. What I have done so far is

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span9">
    Level 1 column
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6">Level 2</div>
      <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle link is :http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/qNsAG/4/show/.

please help to review it. seems I didn't get it in the right way. Because the right result is kind like the picture below. I don't know if i missed something . Could someone please help me ?thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what you're looking for I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/AxMg3/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row show-grid">
        <div class="span9">
            Level 1 column
            <div class="row show-grid">
                <div class="span6">Level 2</div>
                <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added in a link to the docs.css from Bootstrap which gives it the styling you were looking for.

l also added a div with the class of container around your code and added in the .show-grid class to the rows.

Comment: Why you code is different from the code in Bootstrap doc ? Is it a bug in bootstrap doc ?

Comment: I have another question. Why the default download Bootstrap component doesn't include the doc.css you used? thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang - the show-grid class can be seen in use here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem It's not meant to actually be used for styling your site. It's only there to illustrate how the rows and spans actually lay themselves out on the page. remember Bootstrap styles are a starting point and our own designs should be used to override theirs. The docs css file is also just there to style the actiual Bootstrap docs pages and not really to be used for your own website.

Comment: I got your mean. `Bootstrap styles are a starting point and our own designs should be used to override theirs.` It is very nice of you to help me .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap single row has size limited to 12. When you add span6 + span3 you get column size 6 and 3 so this row has size 9 and you have 3 columns left. See span and offset.

Comment: Could you please help me to find why didn't I get the page looks like the pic shown above ? what I got so far is very ugly .thanks.